# Cork the [bottleneck]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The [bottleneck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bottleneck) is a 6 year old tag which has a wiki literally copied from the respective [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottleneck) page and only 98 questions.

Should this tag be burninated?

Comment: Why? How are we going to tag questions about bottlenecks then?

Comment: @ForceBru search a good question where [bottleneck] would be as sole tag in the question valid.

Comment: @ForceBru See [The Death of Meta Tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/): "*The reason meta-tags are a problem is that they do not describe the content of the question... If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag.*" Surely no bottleneck-experts are using the `[bottleneck]` tag to find questions to answer about bottlenecks.

Comment: No, but the system will find them.  If you tag with [bottleneck] then very high odds that Mike Dunlavey will see the question on his front page.

Comment: @apsillers actually, these bottleneck experts are using the `[bottleneck]` tag to look for questions. Just not here. It's quite popular on glassblowing.stackexchange.com

Comment: Maybe tag them `[MikeDunlavy]` if that's the real purpose?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I went through the [bottleneck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bottleneck) questions and removed the tag. I was slightly surprised by the high quality of the questions: 50-60% of them were well-researched and had plots, screenshots, outputs from various profilers and good grammar. These didn't warrant any additional actions. I tried to improve other questions by capitalizing popular abbreviations and [the first-person singular personal pronoun](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_%28pronoun%29), formatting the code and removing clutter.

Overall, I casted 10-15 close votes (most popular reason was "too broad" and some questions asked for a tool) and < 5 downvotes. ~4 questions were already closed.

The bottleneck has been corked.

[image: done]

Comment: Drink some wine? Good idea.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, that tag doesn't really serve any clear purpose other than it being a meta-tag. So you've encountered a "bottleneck"? That's about as descriptive as tagging a question with "problem". And there are already several other valid tags out there that could be applicable yet are more descriptive. Overall I don't see a need for the tag.

Given the low amount of questions with that tag it seems to be an ideal candidate for some elbow grease. Go over the questions, remove the tag, and see if it can use any other edits to make it better, or perhaps even close votes if they are off topic.

Comment: Poking around I found some questions that would need closing rather than just retagging.

Comment: Yep, I saw a couple as well.