# Why do people have a little [pun] with their retag and burninate requests?

Tags: discussion, meta, burninate-system

Every now and then I see a retag or burninate request in Meta. They seem to be relatively easy to identify as they normally include puns and play of words in their titles. For example:

- [This tag should not be [legal]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295117/this-tag-should-not-be-legal)
- [Close the [art] gallery](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295520/close-the-art-gallery)
- [Should we throw the [corners] in the corner?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295233/should-we-throw-corners-in-the-corner)
- [this tag has no [value]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294230/this-tag-has-no-value)
- [[game] over. Insert coin to burninate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294089/game-over-insert-coin-to-burninate/)
- [Cleaning up after the [third-party] and such like](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294849/cleaning-up-after-the-third-party)
- [We need [less] no more](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293664/we-need-less-no-more/)
- [Do we need to be [changed]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293590/do-we-need-to-be-changed)
- [Now hiring: must have the [drive] to burninate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293591/now-hiring-must-have-the-drive-to-burninate)
- [No need to pay [attribute]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284992/no-need-to-pay-attribute/)
- [Let [shellscript] burn in [shell]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292023/let-shellscript-burn-in-shell/)
- [Kill [die] dead!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290645/kill-die-dead)
- [Empty the [trash] and the [recycle-bin]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288762/empty-the-trash-and-the-recycle-bin)
- [Cork the [bottleneck]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289933/cork-the-bottleneck)
- [[auction] off this tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295888/auction-off-this-tag?cb=1)

Nothing against it, I'm just curious as it seems to happen more often in that type of questions than in other types (I have nothing to prove this point though). Is it just coincidence, or is it like a Stack Exchange/Stack Overflow *tradition*?

Comment: Because `Meta == FUN!` (?)

Comment: Because we squash "fun" everywhere else, and people like a bit of humor?

Comment: I've noticed that if one of these requests does not have a punny title, someone will quickly edit it into a pun, whether the author likes it or not. So, seems to be a very much demanded tradition now.

Comment: @Kendra it looks like that. I tried search in [the many memes of meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta) but didn't find any reference to this

Comment: Why do you *think*?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET You just missed a beautiful opportunity. "Because we squash [fun] everywhere else, and people like a bit of humor?" might have been more appropriate. :-P

Comment: Can you add some of my stuff, too? =) http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294901/is-this-tag-a-forgery http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289771/a-timely-burnination-request I tried my best to make good puns, but these issues still didn't get enough attention to be resolved, though...

Comment: Foolow-up question: is this new tradition strong enough to justify [must](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/294548/revisions) [haz](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/295263/revisions) [punz](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/295466/revisions)? ([Some](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/281542/revisions) disagree.)

Comment: I'm guilty of at least three of the ones in your list..

Comment: @lc., Actually, it was [Burninate all the (fun)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268592/burninate-all-the-fun)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro You should change the title to "It's not punny!"

Comment: It isn't funny if you have to explain it.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro: This definitively deserves [an entry in the *Many Memes of Meta*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/257542#257542) - I've just posted one. Feel free to improve!

Comment: Added one more, that's in hot Q list. :-)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET +100 to *we squash "fun" everywhere else*

Comment: In my first burninate request I added some good pun but didn't realize it. Maybe it's just destiny.

Comment: [Here's another one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343030/4284627): This tag is [history]

Comment: I'm waiting for the day when [tag:tag] gets burninated and people go wild with their (deep breath) "tag" tag burnination request post title puns (that would be one word in German). To one-up this, item data in inventories in Minecraft has a tag called "tag", so you could potentially have a "'tag' tag" tag.

Answer (score 187, accepted):

Tag discussion are generally boring, dull, and uninteresting. They are administrative minutiae, and the posts themselves tend to be formulaic (with no disrespect intended to the posters -- it's the topic itself):

> [foo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foo) is ambiguous because it could refer to [wishyfoo](http://example.com/wishyfoo) or [kungfoo](http://example.com/kungfoo). We should disambiguate this.

And then everyone says "Aye", because there's no room for debate. This is the stuff of [C-SPAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C-SPAN#Senate_and_House_of_Representatives).

A joke in your title is a way to capture some interest and get a few more clicks than you otherwise would for your proposal.

Comment: You forgot to mention "boring".

Comment: plus one for mentioning c-span.

Comment: The only issue is the puns need to make sense.  A pun title for pun's sake is worthy of a downvote.

Comment: Wait wait wait... some people don't *like* watching C-SPAN?!

Comment: Adding to this, the vast majority have the same exact title, e.g. "Burninate [countryside]", which makes them especially prone to being shaken up a bit. If other classes of questions always had the same title, I suspect the same thing would happen.

Answer (score 69):

It's not a coincidence, just a Meta quirk. I'm not sure when it originated, but it happens often enough that people notice it and keep the trend rolling. It's not required, but I have seen tag burnination requests get downvoted for not using a pun in the title if they were posted by someone who has been around the community long enough that they should know the drill.

Comment: But I've downvoted burninate requests for a crappy pun.  So pun at your own risk

Comment: @psubsee2003 so we have a critical audience, I see...

Comment: @psubsee2003 it sounds like using a non-crappy pun is the best way to avoid downvotes :)

Answer (score 55):

As Josh states, having a canned message of "Should [x] be removed" or "[x] is ambiguous and should be removed" etc. gets old quick, and is also actually harder to search for and recognize.

To solve this, witty burninate messages began. Meta in many ways is its own culture and this is just one of those nuances that it has taken on. Personally I like it, because of `insert-meta-meme-here`<sup>**1**</sup>.

In fact, burninate itself ([not urinate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/282927/1026459)) [came from a meme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/101417/178816) which involved Trogdor the Burninator. As a result you will often see him taking care of tags himself.

[image]

<sub>**1**.

 - its-always-friday-in-iceland

 - fun

 - waffles

 - 6 to 8 weeks

 - hand drawn circles

 - unicorns

 [The Many Memes of Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19478/178816)</sub>

Comment: And for posterity the original [TROGDOR the BURNiNATOR](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7gz1DIIxmEE) and all his magistracy.

Comment: @ErikPhilips: Here's a link to the video on the official Homestar Runner channel: [Strong Bad Email #58 - Dragon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=90X5NJleYJQ). And [here's the same animation on the homestarrunner.com website](https://homestarrunner.com/sbemail58.html).

Answer (score 8):

> Is it just coincidence, or is it like a Stack Exchange/Stack Overflow tradition?

This may be a coincidence, but it exists on other Meta sites too, here on Meta Unix:

- [What's your input on [/input]?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3538/50687)
- [Should we be using the [/users] tag? And how do we account for [/accounts]?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3535/50687)

And Meta Super User:

- [Let's put [preview] in the rear-view](https://meta.superuser.com/q/9318/267546)
- [Too many [options] to choose from](https://meta.superuser.com/q/9227/267546)
- [Time to downgrade [upgrade]](https://meta.superuser.com/q/8567/267546)

Users are really creative.

Comment: [Burning \[books\]](http://meta.superuser.com/q/8196) is a great one... I sense some time overlap with the advance of p(h)unny over here - perhaps that is because there is an overlap in Meta users on this and SU as well.

Comment: @Jongware - Keep in mind, not too long ago mSO was *the* meta for the entire exchange. So while mSU still held their site related topics, those users still had to come to mSO in order to address exchange related issues.