# ​[auction] off this tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

[auction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/auction) tag has [74](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/auction) questions out of which [14](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bauction%5D%20closed%3Ayes) are closed. [auction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/auction) is being used mostly in two cases

- When some one is looking for sample or open source projects related to auctioning
- When the OP is working on an auction project or website

In both cases the tag adds no value to the question and most of these questions look like off-topic for Stack Overflow. I think we should burninate this tag.

[dfeuer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295907/2246380) mentions some cases where auction might be valid like auction theory in such cases we could create and use a more specific tag like [auction-theory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/auction-theory) and [josilber](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295888/auction-off-auction#comment201819_295907) also mentions about combinatorial auctions in which case we can create the specific tag [combinatorial-auction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/combinatorial-auction). The tag [auction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/auction) is ambiguous as [its](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30596598/2246380) [majorly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29618498/2246380) [used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26585603/2246380) [for](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24551302/2246380) [describing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5024981/2246380) [an](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3486180/2246380) [auction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6492469/2246380) [site](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8386025/2246380) [or](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6634522/2246380) [product](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5195226/2246380). I suggest while we burninate the tag if we come across valid uses for [auction-theory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/auction-theory) or [combinatorial-auction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/combinatorial-auction) we can add them to those posts along we tag wiki/excerpt mentioning the usage.

Comment: I recommend `[auction] off this tag` for your title.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Behold!

Comment: @ace I really don't know. Maybe it changed some time ago, but I had problems earlier creating titles that start with `[`

Comment: I'd argue for tagging combinatorial auction questions with auction theory as well, since they are just a special case and this (to-be-created) tag is not getting enough good questions to justify splintering it. Most of the questions tagged with [tag:auction] currently are very poor (which is too bad, since auction theory/market design is the coolest branch of economics).

Comment: @Docteur that's very tricky clickbait

Answer (score 8):

Let me play devil's advocate here:

There are a lot of kinds of auctions about, and a whole [branch of economics and mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auction_theory) to deal with them. Could some of these issues come up in a computational context? I would imagine so.

Furthermore, in the world of computerized auctions, there are all sorts of potentially interesting issues related to timing attacks, information leakage, denial of service, etc., that may well take on a different flavor in the context of an auction. I don't see anything inherently wrong with recognizing that with a tag.

Comment: I agree -- some types of auctions, e.g. [combinatorial auctions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_auction) are known to be computationally challenging. To me it seems [tag:auction] needs a cleanup, not a burnination.

Comment: @josilber and dfeuer I added your concerns to the question,

Comment: But term "auctions" is broad and obviously attracts misuse.  Therefore it should be burned and replaced with good tags, if any are needed.

Comment: Using this line of argumentation, everything which might at some point need aid of computer programs should be on-topic. Are we going to have tags for cars and space shuttles too?

Comment: @Lundin if there were algorithms that pertained specifically to cars and space shuttles, then we should.

Comment: @Lundin Auction theory is about as tied to programming as graph theory is (although it's a more "applied" field). You have a basic environment (nodes and edges for one; buyers, sellers, budgets and goods for the other) and you need to run an algorithm to solve for something. In economics, we often lump "auction theory" and "matching theory" together as "market design". Donald Knuth, author of the Art of Programming, made central contributions to the latter. Have a look: http://web.stanford.edu/~alroth/papers/engineer.pdf Admittedly, there's little on auction theory on SO (yet?).

Comment: @Frank Sorry, but "auction theory" seems like a whole lot economics and very little programming. It is still an _application purpose_, it is not a _computer algorithm_. Just because something is complex doesn't make it programming. As previously mentioned, there is a lot of complexity and special branch-specific practices involved in making software for cars or space shuttles as well. But that doesn't necessarily mean we should run off and create tags for every single area of application where software is used.

Comment: @Lundin Okay, yeah, I see your point and now agree. One purpose of having a tag is so that people might follow it (which I think is enough reason), but my whole argument is based on a hypothetical set of questions; if I actually start seeing some, I might consider making the tag, though.