# Stop [jumping] around

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

[jumping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jumping) is being (mis)used in various different questions, such as posts related to:

- game mechanics & gaming engine
- microprocessor programming
- audio player
- css & navigation
- page anchor / size

I think it should be removed as it is ambiguous and it conveys different meaning to different users. Before I start to edit / vote to close the questions, I wanted to hear from the Stack Overflow community first.

---

As of Jan 20th, 2016 the [jumping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jumping) tag has less than 20 questions and the tag wiki has been changed to :

> "DO NOT USE THIS TAG; It is ambiguous. Instead, tag your post with what languages or frameworks you're using."

Comment: [referencing here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295583/why-do-people-have-a-little-pun-with-their-retag-and-burninate-requests) I think the title should be something like "Should we [jump] this tag out of the list". Ok, I'm bad at this

Comment: Also, I don't see any real use for it and it has no wiki and only 99 questions tagged

Comment: Send [jumping] off the deep end?

Comment: @RobertLongson much better!

Comment: Man, I know we can do a good pirate pun here, but I'm drawing blanks :(.

Comment: @Braiam do you mean you are "drawing planks"?

Comment: @codeMagic maybe :S

Comment: @RobertLongson Stop [jumping] around :)

Comment: How did this tag get created in the first place? Or is auto created?

Comment: The oldest existing tag was added to a question by Shog, but I doubt that was the first time that tag was used. It's racked up 80 questions since burnination

Comment: I've gotten the tag down to 55 questions. And possibly flagged an additional 12-15 questions. At this point, it would be helpful for a >3k rep user to help with the cleanup. With a lot of the posts remaining, I don't have the experience to make the correct decision.

Comment: Additionally, I've had a wiki edit approved: "_DO NOT USE THIS TAG; It is ambiguous. Instead, tag your post with what languages or frameworks you're using._"

Comment: Burnination completed, 0 questions remaining with the tag [jumping].