# Return this [delivery] to sender

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

The [delivery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delivery) tag is vague, has no wiki, and doesn't seem to be able to stand on its own. There are currently 119 questions with the tag, with usages ranging from:

- [Physical package delivery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30605505/830125)
- [Email delivery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30507362/830125)
- [Software deployments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29457481/830125)

Can it be eliminated?

Comment: Your physical package delivery example made me cry.

Comment: @JackieChiles YES! The [delivery] now complies with the standards of burnination

Comment: @BhargavRao obligatory reference: [Why do people have a little \[pun\] with their retag and burninate requests?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295583/839601)

Answer (score 2):

This is done!  Mods, please mark [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Comment: Has this burnation ever been started? Did you do the burnation on your own?

Comment: @BDL how many users are needed in concert to deal with a 119 questions tag in 2 years and a half? Heck, that's enough time for at least 30% to be deleted by good ol' roomba.

Comment: @Braiam: It's not about how may users are needed. If there are more than 50 questions, then you have to follow the [burnation process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination). The proposal has to be featured before any action beeing taken in order to gain enough visibility. Cleaning up tags with more than a handful questions single-handed usually just causes troubles afterwards.

Comment: @BDL ... are you aware that this one was posted on 2015, right? Why are you retroactively asking people to do a task before they were even aware that such task was needed. Also, the 50 cutoff was more of a guidance rather than a rule. The whole burnination process is also a guidance.

Comment: @Braiam: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by retroactively. I asked because the answer has been posted 21h ago (~5 minutes before I left the comment). I wanted to know whether the user who posted the answer did the cleanup now on his own or whether he just found that tag to be empty. What I'm sure about is that guidelines given in the FAQ can't simply be ignored just because you think that's fine.

Comment: @BDL what would be the course of action in any case? The tag is done for. The user is just informing that the tag was done. Why make a problem when there's none? Or you disagree with the burnination? Make your case in that case.

Comment: @Braiam "Make your case in that case" ... case closed.

Comment: Hello @BDL, we were reviewing the open burnination request queue on another question and noticed that this one had actually been done at some point in the past but was showing as open.  So the consensus was we should ask mods to mark it as done.  We could also mark it as declined, delete it, etc.