# This tag can't be ignored, [ignoring]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

[ignoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ignoring) currently has 26 questions.  It has no wiki.

I propose that we burninate the ignoring tag. It passes the tests of the [When to burninate question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191):

It ranges from ignoring files for source control, characters in string parsing, css formating & logic errors.

Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous? **No**

Is the concept described even on-topic for the site? **Sometimes**

Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post? **No**

Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts? **No**

As ryanyuyu has pointed out, some of those that are to do with source control may need to be re-tagged with [ignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ignore) if applicable.

Comment: A few of these questions seem related to [tag:ignore], which is related to source control.  But a lot of them are just using the tag as a keyword.  This tag should die a fiery death.

Comment: Replace with [[tag:ignorant]]

Comment: That tag is [ignoring] a tag's purpose

Comment: Why do you say "no" to "the concept described even on-topic for the site"? Writing an SVN or Git config file is programming.

Comment: @acbabis but such information can and should be conveyed on the question body/title, not in tags.

Comment: @Braiam I agree; just sayin'

Comment: I honestly thought this tag was added by editors who had lost their flag tool :^)

Comment: While we're at it, we should think of a different name for [tag:ignore], because it's massively abused by people who want to 'ignore something', but not in a context of version control. I just removed three from the newest 10.

Comment: I see that burnination is already underway. I recommend adding [gitignore] to the few questions remaining, where appropriate. We might also consider creating an [svn-ignore] tag since 244 posts contain "svn ignore"

Comment: I love the clever titles that show up on tag cleanup posts!

Comment: I hate the clever titles that show up on tag cleanup post. Also, there are several tags I'd like to see burninated, but I can't for the life of me think of any good pun titles.

Comment: @MrLister I don't think a pun is mandatory (to start with). If posted without one, somebody will soon edit one in, I'm sure.

Comment: @Angew I know. That was mentioned elsewhere too. I was just trying to be snarky. To be honest, I wanted to shutdown the [shutdown] tag, but it has many questions about writing shutdown bash scripts, so it's on topic.

Comment: "I hate the clever titles that show up on tag cleanup post." the idea of people being "funny" on here is (a) staggeringly tedious (b) a tremendous waste of time

Comment: @JoeBlow Sorry, but you appear to be in the minority.  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295583/why-do-people-have-a-little-pun-with-their-retag-and-burninate-requests/295590#295590

Comment: It's sad and embarrassing.  It's not my site - so people can and should do what they want, of course.  Anyone can and should walk around with B.O. or toilet paper sticking to their shoes, if they want to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [ignoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ignoring) tag has been cleaned up.