# Sacrifices To Trogdor: [referrals]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

So I was looking thru questions today and came across the [referrals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/referrals) tag.  It has no tag wiki and no followers.  It seems to mostly be used when talking about referring urls for HTTP requests (though it has been used for other things).  It also doesn't seem like it is a tag that would really add much to a post (assuming someone is at least trying to describe their problem).

Is this worth improving?  Or should we just remove the tag from questions and wait for the roomba to offer it to Trogdor?

Comment: I don't understand what "wait for the roomba to offer it to Trogdor" means. I'm assuming it's a reference to something. Could the title please be changed to not be so niche?

Comment: @Thunderforge Time to be indoctrinated in the [ways of SE memes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta) and [burninate requests](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295583/why-do-people-have-a-little-pun-with-their-retag-and-burninate-requests/295590#295590).

Comment: There's got to be a pun for this though.

Comment: @Thunderforge asking meta users to abandon tradition for your benefit is a futile request. http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/trogdor

Comment: @BSMP No [referrals] please.

Comment: -1, no image of ritual sacrifice to Trogdor.

Comment: Get enough `[referrals]` and your next burnination is free!