# steinberg-asio is all noise

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, burninate-request, synonym-request

There is a tag [steinberg-asio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/steinberg-asio) which should be a synonym of [asio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asio) as they are used to describe the same technology.

Comment: Clear case, yes. From the [tag:asio] wiki: "It was developed by Steinberg ..." (A difficult one to [Pun Upon](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295583/why-do-people-have-a-little-pun-with-their-retag-and-burninate-requests) though.)

Comment: Interestingly - `asio` is a syn for `boost-asio`... even though that tag description says: *For questions about the Boost.Asio C++ library for asynchronous IO — use [tag:boost-asio] to avoid ambiguity.*

Comment: No one pays any attention to tag descriptions. Witness the number of .NET questions that get tagged [tag:assembly]. The advice in the tag excerpt to use the [tag:.net-assembly] tag instead is heeded only rarely. I say this not simply to exercise my cynicism muscle, but to point out that we should take care in merging/synonymizing tags that are potentially ambiguous, lest we get ourselves into more of a bind than we were to start with.

Comment: @RadLexus "steinberg-asio is all noise"?

Answer (score 11):

To prevent confusion (there's a [boost-asio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost-asio) tag, and many of the [asio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asio) tagged question have the [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) tag), [steinberg-asio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/steinberg-asio) and [boost-asio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost-asio) should be the main tags, and [asio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asio) should be removed.