# Merge [entity-relationship-model] tag into [entity-relationship]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Last I checked *entity-relationship* has 2217 questions whereas *entity-relationship-model* has only 114. The definitions of both tags indicate that they are describing the same thing. Therefore, I suggest we merge the less popular one into the more popular one.

[image: both tags description]

Comment: [**Establish a closer relationship between tag entities \[entity-relationship-model\] and \[entity-relationship\]**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295583/)

Comment: It is the very model of a modern [tag:entity-relationship]!

Comment: Related: [Should [erd] and [entity-relationship] be merged?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417777/should-erd-and-entity-relationship-be-merged?cb=1)