# Should [erd] and [entity-relationship] be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Dharman recently marked [Merge [entity-relationship-model] tag into [entity-relationship]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361521/merge-entity-relationship-model-tag-into-entity-relationship) as completed and, at the same time, combined [erd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/erd) and [er-diagrams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/er-diagrams) as well. However, he requested a separate Meta post be created for the third step of merging [erd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/erd) and [entity-relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-relationship).

So, should we now merge [erd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/erd) and [entity-relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-relationship), given that they refer to the same thing (ERDs)?

Statistics:

- [entity-relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-relationship) is used on about 2800 questions
- [erd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/erd) is used on about 1100 questions
- about 200 questions have both [entity-relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-relationship) and [erd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/erd)

Comment: As said in chat: none of these should exist. Making it bigger would only make it seems like an insurmountable task.

Comment: I can't think of a case where ER won't amount to a diagram (hence ERD) so I'd say merge. I didn't catch the chat Braiam mentions but ERD, UML, and the other modelling languages are on-topic (if they were to become off-topic on SO which SE site would those questions be asked and answered on?).

Comment: @bad_coder Well, strictly the abstract model and the diagram of it are two separate things. You don't need to draw it to have entity-relationships, and they're as often represented in runtime objects, code, or database schemas as they are represented in diagrams. That said, disambiguating these 3800 questions is hardly possible

Comment: @Bergi that would however give you a criteria for 2 tags: the one's that are about a diagram and the ones that aren't... From that perspective merging could be a mistake.

Comment: @bad_coder Yes, exactly. But there's probably many already that are mis-tagged if we use that criterion, and I'm not sure if merging them would make it a lot worse. So I'm indifferent.

Comment: @Bergi merge would make it worst for users searching (might actually be a kind of disaster). Retaging can be done as a result of this post or be left up to users who'll care to curate those tags in the future; the main issue is reaching a consensus and writing up clear tag guidance. (Coincidentally I was looking into UML earlier this month, the tag should be split per diagram type imo)...

Comment: @Bergi I'm not asking about splitting a tag into multiple, but the opposite, so [meta-tag:tag-disambiguation] is inappropriate here.

Answer (score 3):

We don't need a separate [erd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/erd) tag.  I'm in favor of merging any tag associated with the off-topic "diagram" into the on-topic "relationship" tag.

Comment: Why do you think diagrams are off-topic?

Comment: @Bergi Because any diagram, artwork, flowchart, or white-board scribbling only gains on-topic-ness by its content.